# I can't redefine operator[] for const structure

Tags: c++, struct, constants, operator-keyword

A have the following code:

```
struct abc {
    abc(int a) : a(a) {}
    
     int operator [] (int t) {
         return t;
     }
    
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    abc const abc1(25);
    int c = abc1[75];

    return 0;
}
```

The error is **"passing ‘const abc’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"**.
I dont understand why this error appears? I do not change the fields of the const structure.

If i write **abc abc1(25);** instead of **abc const abc1(25);** it's no error.

Comment: Make your method `const` -> `int operator [] (int t) const {return t;}`.

Comment: Imagine that you don't have access to the code of `operator[]`. Can you tell whether it changes anything or not?

Comment: In C++, a class can specify two APIs commingled together.  One is the `const` API, and the other is the *mutable* API.  A non-const object can access the `const` API and the *mutable* API.  A `const` object can only access the `const` API.